# How to compare list of records against database in Java?

Tags: java

How to compare list of records against database? I have more than 1000 records in list and need to validate against database. How to validate each record from list to database? Select all the data from database and stored in list, then have to compare the values? Please advise...

The below code lists values to validate against database.

```
private void validatepart(HttpServletRequest req, Vector<String> errors) {
    Parts Bean = (Parts)req.getAttribute("partslist");
    Vector<PartInfo> List = Bean.getPartList();
    int sz = partList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        PartInfo part = (PartInfo)partList.elementAt(i);
        System.out.println(part.getNumber());
        System.out.println(part.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "validate". Do you mean what objects in your code are already in the database, or what records from the database are in your list already?

Comment: user enter product code in screen, that product code already in another database. So before proceed the process , need to confirm the that product code is valid.Example :product code =523652 in list, i am validate this part equal to database value or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by compare. If it's just one field then executing a query such as `select * from parts_table where part_number = ?`. It's not that much of a stretch to add more fields to that query. If nothing is returned you know it doesn't exist.

If you need to compare and know exactly which values are different then you can try something like this

```
List<String> compareObjects(PartInfo filePart, PartInfo dbPart) {
    List<String> different = new LinkedList<String>();

    if (!filePart.getNumber().equals(dbPart.getNumber())) {
        different.add("number");
    }
    //repeat for all your fields
    return different;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have two fields to compare against the database.So if i have 500 records in list to compare , 500 times SQL going to Run ?

Comment: 500 queries isn't a lot but if you're concerned about performance then you can always do one query and then compare each item in memory

Answer (score 0):

If your list of objects that you need to validate against the database includes a primary key, then you could just build a list of those primary key values and run a query like:

```
SELECT <PRIMARY KEY FIELD> FROM <TABLE> WHERE <PRIMARY_KEY_FIELD> IN <LIST OF PRIMARY KEYS> SORT BY <PRIMARY KEY FIELD> ASC;
```

Once you get that list back, you can compare the results. My instinct would be to put your data (and the query results too) into a Set object and then call removesAll() to get the items not in the database (reverse this for items in the database but not in your set):

```
yourDataSet.removeAll(queryResults);
```

This assumes that you have an `equals()` method implemented in your `PartInfo` object. You can see the Java API [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) for more details.